# How to align my JTextField to center

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

So I have two panels, the first one containing a textfield and Label:

```
public class Panel1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


//Common variables

    JTextField val;



public Component panel1() {

    // Panel 1 to add labels and textfields

    final JPanel order = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5));{

      order.add(new JLabel("Current Value:", JLabel.CENTER));
      order.add(val = new JTextField(3));
```

and the other panel one containing buttons:

```
     JPanel buttons = new JPanel();


      JButton add;
      buttons.add(add=new JButton("+"));
    add.setToolTipText("Pressing the button will find total cost");


      add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
      {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

      });

      JButton sub;
      buttons.add(sub = new JButton("-"));
      sub.setToolTipText("Pressing the button will save the record to .csv file");

      sub.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 


            }   

        });



      JButton reset;
      buttons.add(reset=new JButton("Clear"));
    reset.setToolTipText("Pressing the button will clear data entered into the screen");

      reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        }   
        });

      JButton quit;
      buttons.add(quit= new JButton("Quit"));
    quit.setToolTipText("Pressing the button will close the window");

       quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.exit(0);

    }


    });



    // Panel to combine rest of the panels to one
    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    main.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    main.add(order);
    main.add(buttons);

    return main;}
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

THE PROBLEM IS THAT MY TEXT FIELD IS NOT ALIGNED. IT SIS COMING IN ROW WITH THE BUTTONS LIKE THIS:

```
                _______    ________     ________    _______  
 Current Value:|_______|   |____+___|  |___-____|  |__reset|
```

I want the Jtextfield(current value) to be up in the center, not with the buttons.

Comment: *"THE PROBLEM IS THAT MY TEXT FIELD IS NOT ALIGNED"*  Really?  It seems the first problem you should sort is that your SHIFT KEY IS STUCK.  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another layout manager.

Try to replace the

```
JPanel order = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5));
```

with

```
JPanel order = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
```

Comment: it still show in the same way

Comment: Read comment of Andrew Thompson and add SSCCE to the question